# Get Total View from three different tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

Hello Everyone I am a Codeigniter Beginner,

In controller I am sending data like-

1

```
$send['rowa'] = $this->db->query("
SELECT sum(views) as rowCount 
  from table_a
")->result();
```

2

```
$send['rowb'] = $this->db->query("
SELECT sum(view_counter) as rowCount 
  from table_b
")->result();
```

3

```
$send['rowc'] = $this->db->query("
SELECT sum(view_counter) as rowCount 
  from table_c
")->result();
```

In view I am using

```
'<=$rowa[0]->rowCount;?>, <=$rowb[0]->rowCount;?>, <=$rowc[0]->rowCount;?>.
```

I am getting the actual output like

> 12, 34, 21.

I want to get the total of

> 12+34+21= 67.

How I can get it?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$send['total'] = $this->db->query("SELECT (SELECT sum(views) as rowCount from table_a)+(SELECT sum(view_counter) as rowCount from table_b)+(SELECT sum(view_counter) as rowCount from table_c) as rowCount;")->result();
```

Which will run

```
SELECT 
(SELECT sum(views) as rowCount from table_a) 
+(SELECT sum(view_counter) as rowCount from table_b)
+(SELECT sum(view_counter) as rowCount from table_c) as rowCount;
```

As every select only returns 1 result this can be used to add the results

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$rowCount